# Whether Replication Possible With Spring Data Couchbase?

Tags: spring-data, couchbase

HI i just want to know whether the XDCR replication is possible with spring data Couchbase. If possible how can i achieve that .please help .
My Code Sample

```
    //configuration class
    @Configuration
    public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public CouchbaseClient couchbaseClient() throws IOException {

        return new CouchbaseClient(Arrays.asList(URI
                .create("http://localhost:8091/pools")), "xxxw", "");

    }

    @Bean
    public CouchbaseTemplate couchbaseTemplate() throws IOException {
        return new CouchbaseTemplate(couchbaseClient());
    }
    } 

       @Document
       public class Person {

    @Field
    String name;


    @Id
    String id; 

    public Person(final String personId, final String personname,
            final int personIdAge, final JSONObject personData) {

        this.id = personId;
        this.name = personname;
        this.age = personIdAge;
        this.body = personData;

    }
}
         //main Test class

        public class Test {

        public static void main(String s[]) {

        try {

            ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                    ApplicationConfig.class);

            CouchbaseTemplate template = context.getBean("couchbaseTemplate",
                    CouchbaseTemplate.class);




        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

How can i achieve repltcaion to elastic search index through spring data couchbase . with this sample classes ..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using elastic search in Couchbase is not dependent on what you client application looks like or whether or not it uses Spring. As long as you are storing data in Couchbase in JSON format things should work fine.

Setting up elastic search is more of an operations task than a development task. Take a look at the instructions at the link below and then run you application code as is. If you have configured everything properly then your data should end up in elastic search.

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-elastic-search/